# Unity 2D shader graph not correct colored

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph

I tried to create outline shader for my Sprite:

[image]

I watched tutorials on YouTube (CodeMonkey and Brackeys) about this, but it worked by half. In Scene Graph I see preview:

[image]

But outline color I so faded:

[image]

And also I can't see this shader on Scene Preview:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your attention

P.S.: Of course I set render pipeline like on this [video](https://youtu.be/5dzGj9k8Qy8)
P.P.S: Material settings:

[image]

P.P.P.S: [Shader file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15RsLAuGaMO-XfELsAfk6gpskpHMHziue/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: could you include the settings (Inspector) of the material you used?

Comment: Oh exactly, i do not set color on material settings. Ok, i see shader on sprite, but outline color still so faded. I added settings to post

Comment: Could you show the rest of the graph you have then I could reproduce it

Comment: @derHugo i added link to shader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first of all you hadn't set the color in the according `Outline Color` slot int he Material settings.

---

Then what you are using is `Add` which results in additive color combining towards white.

Since your original texture isn't fully black but grey-ish the outline color is added to the already existing color(s) making it also lighter!

Instead you could use a [`Blend`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.shadergraph@6.9/manual/Blend-Node.html) node and re-use the output of the `Substract` node as blend texture (Opacity).

Then you have to play a bit with the mode but I think maybe `Overwrite` or `PinLight` would be what you want.

(Actually you wouldn't need the additional `Multiply` node for the Outline Color)

[image]

---

Btw before you added your file I just reproduced one from scratch and it is way less complex than yours ;)

[image]